# Numpy array: multiplication array for each row

Tags: python, numpy

I have two array `a` and `b` such that b's shape is a row of `a`. I want to multiply `b` to each row of `a` so for example,

```py
#a

[[1,2,3]
 [4,5,6]
 [7,8,9]]

#b
[1,3,2]

# a times b
[[1,6,6]
 [4,15,12]
 [7,24,18]]
```

Is there any way to perform it?

Comment: As simple as `a * b`

Comment: See broadcasting as well, multiplication will yield expecting results only if the dimensions make sense. 
https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html

Answer (score 2):

This is actually the expected output when using numpy. So in your case:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]])
b = np.array([1,3,2])
c = a*b
```

c will be:

```
array([[ 1,  6,  6],
       [ 4, 15, 12],
       [ 7, 24, 18]])
```